# Выделение месяца и года в отдельную таблицу

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Есть таблица employee_salary со следующими полями:

```
id, employee_id, year, month, salary.
```

В месяц salary может добавляться несколько раз (бонусы, к примеру).

Стоит ли эту таблицу разделить на две? Т.е. на эти:

`employee_salary_month` с полями `id, empolyee_id, year, month`

`employee_salary` с полями `employee_salary_month_id, salary`

Кроме отсутствия избыточных данных, какие ещё есть преимущества у данной схемы?

Comment: не понятно зачем бы вообще могло понадобиться что то делить. А год-месяц вообще лучше хранить в одном поле с типом даты

Comment: А это не нарушает никакую нормальную форму? Ведь данные (а точнее, дата) дублируются. У меня, на самом деле, есть ещё некоторые данные, ассоциированные с месяцом (допустим, tax), поэтому необходимо создать отдельную таблицу для месяца.

Comment: Про год-месяц согласен, так и сделаю. Типом "дата" пользоваться удобнее для сравнения.

Comment: конечно это нарушает НФ, если что то храниться дважды. И что значит "ассоциированная с месяцем". зачем вообще месяцы выделять. Отталкиваться надо от реальной жизни. Если идет просто набор выплат, то они тупо пишутся в одну таблицу. Если надо получать данные суммарно за месяц или суммарно по сотруднику или еще как то, то это уже к хранению не имеет никакого отношения, все данные, которые могут быть рассчитаны, получаются по необходимости запросами из исходных данных и не хранятся. (Кроме случаев оптимизации по скорости, но это вообще отдельная песня)

Comment: Ну если нарушает, то не лучше тогда разделить на две таблицы? :)
Пример ассоциированной с месяцем информации: Статус выплаты (выплачено / не выплачено) зарплаты сотруднику в конкретный месяц.

Comment: Сущности "месяц зарплаты" не существует. Есть дата операции, возможно есть "отчетный месяц", к которому по бухгалтерии надо относить данную выплату. И то и другое - обычные, не ключевые, атрибуты такой сущности, как "выплата"

Comment: т.е. теоретически месяц можно было бы считать отдельной сущностью, но она тогда ни как не должна была бы быть связана с конкретным сотрудником. Т.е. отдельного ID у связки сотрудник-дата быть не может.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.